# Load values in one View from different Models and Controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, telerik

I have a View where I call a Partial View with different Model and different controller.
The partial View contains a grid who use the pk of the main view to populate itself.
How can I load both models values in one method?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Needing to call more than one controller is generally a sign of a poor design. The one controller should make calls to two separate parts of your business (or some other abstraction) layer to get the two sets of model data. Failing that, one controller will need to invoke the other to get its part of the model.

You can then combine these two models into a single view model, which can be passed to the main view. The main view then passes the partial view the part of the overall model that it's interested in.

Comment: Isn't it poor design to call two different model from one controller? We're already using this, but I'm not sure that 's a clean code solution.

Comment: Let's assume you have a login page and user admin page. Both need data from the `Users` model. Would you really have them both in one controller though?

Answer (score 0):

You should consider splitting your project into layers.  You already know the controller and view layers, now add another layer called ViewModel..  Then implement containers in each view model to satisfy related and unrelated content.  For example:

```
[HttpGet]
public void ViewModel1(){
   public ViewModel1(){
      using(var db = new CustomerEntities()){
          Customers = db.Customers.Where(
              p=>p.isActive = true &&    
              p.hasOrder=true && 
              p.AR > 0);
      }
   }
   public Customer SelectedCustomer {get;set;}
   public IEnumerable<Customer> Customers {get;set;}
   public ViewModel2 VMCustomerBilling {get;set;}
   public ViewModel3 VMCustomerOrders {get;set;}

   public void Post(){
        VMCustomerBilling = new ViewModel2(SelectedCustomer);
        VmCustomerOrders = new ViewModel3(SelectedCustomer);
   }
}

[HttpPost]
 public void ViewModel1(ViewModel1 vm){
   if(ModelState.IsValid){
      vm.Post();
   }
   return View(vm);
 }
```

This is called containment, as you are containing other semi-related content.  ViewModel1 would show current customers (for example). You can leave the Billing and Orders information empty until post back indicating which Customer was selected.  This is shown in the Post method of the ViewModel, do the same thing for the order table.

In the view, all you need to do is add Partial views of the Billing and Order views, and in the main view only display them is there is content.